# Is it possible to include interpreter path (or set any default code) when I create new python file in Pycharm?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

I haven't been able to find anything and I am not sure if this is the place I should be asking...

But I want to include the path to my interpreter in every new project I create.  The reason being is that I develop locally and sync my files to a linux server.  It is annoying having to manually type `#! /users/w/x/y/z/bin/python` every time I create a new project. Also would be nice to include certain imports I use 90% of the time.

I got to thinking, in the program I produce music with you can set a default project file.  Meaning, when you click new project it is set up how you have configured (include certain virtual instruments, effects, etc).

Is it possible to do this or something similar with **IDE**, and more specifically, **Pycharm**?

Comment: You want to include path in your project files as `#! /users/w/x/y/z/bin/python`, or you want to run with specific interpreter from PyCharm?

Comment: doesn't `#! /users/w/x/y/z/bin/python` point to the interpreter to use?  In any case, I want that line to be included in all project files I create.

Comment: I believe it's not the best choice because if you move that project to another computer then you need to change path in files to actual interpreter or change path of existing interpreter, sounds little bit harsh. I believe what you are looking for is [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html)

Comment: I am moving it to another computer, that is the point :).  I am developing locally on and deploying the project onto a linux machine...I need to specify the interpreter using that one line of code.  I don't even need an interpreter in Pycharm locally...All I want to do is include one line of code - the interpreter path, on every python file I create.

Comment: I think that would be a lot of pain. why don't you just run python script with `python script.py`?

Comment: Well, I am using a virtual environment and I don't have permissions to create the environment variable that would allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open **File** in the main menu and click **Default Settings**, collapse the **Editor** then click **File and Code Templates**, in the **Files** tab click on the **+** sign and create a new **Template**, give the new template a name and extension, in the editor box put your template content, in your case `#! /users/w/x/y/z/bin/python` **apply** and **OK**. After that everytime you open a project, select that template to include default lines you want. You could make number of templates.

Comment: Fantastic - Exactly what I was trying to find!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top-right tab with your project name, then go `Edit Configurations` and there you can change the interpreter.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for :)

I want the interpreter path to be included in all new python files I create.  IE `#! /users/w/x/y/z/bin/python`